# Запуск ReactJS+express+mongodb на виртуальном хостинге

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Я только начинаю изучать React  и у меня возник такой вопрос. Раньше, чтобы разместить приложение на хостинге, я просто выполнял команду npm run build, билдил и заливал все это дело на хостинг. Теперь же у меня появилась серверная часть, где я работаю с Express и MongoDB. Можно ли как то залить это на виртуальный хостинг, обходя VDS/VPS? Спасибо

Comment: В чём заключается проблема?